# Axios get multiple JSON end points and save into state (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to update my axios get request from 1 JSON end point to 3 JSON end points and then save the posts into the component state.

https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-get-requests-gerjq - I have console.log(posts) but it does not seem any of the objects are being saved into the state.

Any idea where I am going wrong?

```
 private getPosts() {
  axios
    .all([
      axios.get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + "https://...."),
      axios.get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + "https://...."),
      axios.get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + "https://www..."),
      axios.get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + "http://api...."),
      axios.get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + "https://www..."),
      axios.get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" + "https://www...")
    ])
    .then(axios.spread((response =>
      response.data.map(post => ({
        id: `${ post.Id || post.jobId }`,
        name: `${ post.Name || post.advertisements[0].title.localization[1].value }`,
        company: `${ post.Company || 'Ohly' }`,
        summary: `${ post.Summary }`
      }))
    )))
    .then(posts => {
      this.setState({
        posts,
        isLoading: false
      });
    })
     // Error catching
    .catch(errors => this.setState({ errors, isLoading: false }));
}
```

Comment: you're not setting them into the state anywhere in your code, you're just fetching the data

Comment: .then(posts => {
        this.setState({
          posts,
          isLoading: false
        });
      }) -- I am setting it here? :/

Comment: you should edit your question to include that code then, as it is now you're just fetching the data

Comment: I have included a link to the full code, but okay will add it in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to access the three responses as three arguments to axios.spread and return the mapped result

```
.then(
    axios.spread((response, response1, response2) => {
      return [...response.data, ...response1.data, ...response2.data].map(
        post => ({
          id: `${post.Id || post.jobId}`,
          name: `${post.Name ||
            post.advertisements[0].title.localization[1].value}`,
          company: `${post.Company || "Ohly"}`,
          summary: `${post.Summary}`,
          url: `${post.AbsoluteUrl || post.adUrl.localization[0].value}`
        })
      );
    })
  )
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-get-requests-3i1uf)

Comment: This looks like the correct solution! https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-get-requests-gerjq - I have implemented this here but still not seeing as posts when I console log :/ Can you fix the working demo link so I can see this solution working?

Comment: Your `working demo` is linked to the current question

Comment: @BennKingy  If you don't know how many requests will be made, you can use this dynamic solution: codesandbox.io/s/multiple-get-requests-7lm42

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend instead of normal setState, try using setState with callback function. 
Just replace your setState code with the code below:

```
this.setState({
      posts,
      isLoading: false
    }, () => {
      console.log(this.state)
    });
```

Instead of console.log, you can use any function as well. But your state will be updated for sure.

Answer (score 0):

for axios multi request please follow this pattern

```
axios.all([
 axios.get('http://google.com'),
 axios.get('http://apple.com')
]).then(axios.spread((googleRes, appleRes) => {
  this.setState({google: googleRes, apple: appleRes});
});
```

you need to store your api data to your state in order to available the request data inside your component.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/multiple-get-requests-gerjq - Could you please edit this to make it work in that pattern? I am a bit lost >.<